# How can I batch apply different watermarks for horizontal and vertical pictures in ImageMagick?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, watermark, imagemagick-convert, mogrify

How can I mass apply different watermarks (horizontal and vertical) on different images (horizontal and vertical)?

I have folder tree with hundreds of PNG files like this (as example):

```
modern
classic
balance
```

I have two watermarks:

```
watermark-horizontal.png
watermark-vertical.png
```

How can I apply horizontal watermark on horizontal photos and vertical watermark on vertical photos?

I can do it for a single photo like this:

```
convert watermark-horizonal.png some-horizontal.png result.png
```

How can I do the same for many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.png
do
   read w h <<< $(convert "$f" -ping -format "%w %h" info: )
   if [ $w -gt $h ]; then
      echo "$f is $h tall and $w wide (landscape)"
      convert watermark-horizonal.png "$f" "wm-$f"
   else
      echo "$f is $h tall and $w wide (portrait)"
      convert watermark-vertical.png "$f" "wm-$f"
   fi
done
```

If you want to recurse, you can do this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*.png" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f
do
   read w h <<< $(convert "$f" -ping -format "%w %h" info: )
   if [ $w -gt $h ]; then
      echo "$f is $h tall and $w wide (landscape)"
   else
      echo "$f is $h tall and $w wide (portrait)"
   fi
done
```

Save in a file called `go`, then type the following in a Terminal

```sh
chmod +x go       # Do this just ONCE to make script executable
./go              # Do this any number of times to run it
```

By the way, I use the following command for my watermarking:

```sh
composite -dissolve 50% -resize "1x1<" -gravity center copyright.png x.png x.png
```

Comment: Look nice I will learn some sh now. Is it possible use `for x in y` with recursion?

Comment: Script is little buggy under windows not works without changes. Whatever it was helpful - you can fix it.